# Pickling-unpickling issue with an AI Model

Tags: python, git, pickle, git-lfs

I am using Google Colab to build an AI model, it uses a pre-trained model from Wav2Lip GitHub repository (https://github.com/Rudrabha/Wav2Lip/blob/master/README.md#getting-the-weights | Wav2lip+ GAN model), which i've downloaded and uploaded on my own repository. I have successfully run the model when i uploaded it on google drive and called it from there. But when i uploaded it on my GitHub repository using git lfs, it is showing a pickling error. I doubt there is an issue with the model. What can i do?

Error:

[error line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrEDW.png)

code cell that gives error:

```
!cd LS_Final && python inference.py --checkpoint_path checkpoints/wav2lip_gan.pth --face "../sample_data/testvid2.mp4" --audio "../sample_data/output1.wav"
```

When i ran the code, the model lip synced any audio over a person's video/image to make it look like the person in the video/image is speaking what's there in the audio. The model was supposed to run and provide me with the output video but its stuck at pickling and unpickling. I have used the same model using google drive and it worked just fine, so i dont think there's anything worng with the model. It is probably related to lfs? I have also checked the python versions and it worked on 3.8(my python version) when on google drive.